# Django save an image asynchronous during a request

Tags: django, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

I need to save an image on Amazon WS S3 using Django.
I have this code:

```
try:
                    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
                    img_temp.write(urllib2.urlopen(urlImageTo Download).read())
                    img_temp.flush()
                    p.image.save('image.jpg', File(img_temp))
                    p.save() //P is an ImageField

                except urllib2.HTTPError:
                    continue
```

I integrated `django-storages` to save directly the image in Amazon S3.
I have to save the image during a request (in the request I have an URL of an image that I have to download it and resave in Amazon S3) but I think that I can to have  this line:

> p.image.save('image.jpg', File(img_temp))

asynchronous.

In this case I can return immediately the response of my request while I can save the image on S3
How can I have this? Is Possible?